# GDAL install on Ubuntu 12.04 works for python 2.x but not python3

Tags: gdal, ubuntu, python-3

I need to install gdal 1.10 or greater to be compatible with python3 on ubuntu 12.04. The machine also has python2 installed.

I followed instructions here [Error While installing GDAL in Ubuntu 12.04](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166965/error-while-installing-gdal-in-ubuntu-12-04). This successfully installed gdal for python2.x but not python3. I tried the command `sudo apt-get install gdal-bin python3-gdal` but am greeted with the error "Unable to locate pacage python3-gdal"

I also tried `sudo pip3 install gdal`

How can I install gdal successfully for python3?

Comment: Is upgrading to 14.04 an option? Then you could use the [python3-gdal](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/trusty/python/python3-gdal) package from the standard repo.

Comment: This is not an option as the ubuntu server is shared

Comment: I was able to upgrade the server and the command `sudo apt-get install gdal-bin python3-gdal` did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UbuntuGIS](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages) contains GDAL 1.10.0-1 with Python3 bindings.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa && sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gdal-bin python3-gdal
```

You could also [build GDAL from source](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildHints) with Python3 support but that would require installing the depending libraries (and solving quite some build issues while you're at it).

Comment: I get the error: `Cannot access PPA (https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntugis-stable) to get PPA information, please check your internet connection` 

my internet connection is working fine. I'm accessing the ubuntu server remotely from a windows machine, if that makes any difference (don't think so)

Comment: My bad, I messed up the PPA link. Try the corrected version.

Comment: Sorry for late answer but it worked! Thank you!